# How to setup a Fast BlackBerry Smart Phone simulator and How to make Code Signing Faster in BlackBerry?

Tags: code-signing, blackberry-simulator

Many times while coding an application for BlackBerry® smartphones, I want to quickly start the BlackBerry® Smartphone Simulator and see what I have achieved so far. Micro-iterative coding is my style of choice. I don’t need to debug any code, I just want to see it running; If it doesn’t work, then I’ll begin debugging.But **launching simulator and checking output is taking so much time** especially while **debugging**. And if I decide to test my code directly in device,**each time Code signing must be do** even if I make any small changes in code,and which is a **very time consuming process and so I felt very much ridiculous during development of the app**. I don't want to continue in this procedure for future developing apps.As I am new to BlackBerry Application development, I have no idea how to fix this time consuming process.So I request you all, to give me your valuable suggestions to overcome this issue, especially on

Issue Priority to be solved:

1. How to load the app faster in device.
2. How to debug or run the code faster in Simulator.

Comment: What is your target platform in simulator? In 5, 6 and 7 you don't have to restar the simulator to redeploy your app.

Comment: The simulator is basically running the actual OS, just with simulated hardware, so it can't really run much faster than a real device would (and device startups are slow in general).  But juanmabaiu is right, you don't have to restart the simulator each time.  Keep it running while you write code, and then just run the project again when ready.  The simulator will pick up the changes.  In fact, if your app is already running in the simulator when you re-run the project, the simulator will automatically restart the running app for you.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain a hot swapping enabled simulator. (most support this feature now). Re running your code will infact just reload the application with new changes. And without restarting the emulator.

As for code signing. It is not needed for an emulator. Only a real device.

Real devices are not always faster at everything. aka file reading. Be warned. Test it on real devices from time to time.